# Permission Files Nescessity and Failed Open Stream

Tags: php, xampp

I just installed XAMPP on Ubuntu and came across this error on my website page...

```
Warning: require_once(core/init.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in 

/opt/lampp/htdocs/lr/start.php on line 44

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'core/init.php' (include_path='.:/opt

/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/lr/start.php on line 44
```

So I then went across and ran several lines of code changing the permissions for `/opt/lampp/htdocs` and the `php.ini` file with this code

```
sudo chmod 777 filename
```

The problem is that I'm still receiving the error from php. So my questions is, what am I missing in terms of which files should be executable so that I can run my code.

Comment: we can't tell you exactly what is wrong without seeing your PHP source code.

Comment: Is this still the case even when it worked with the previous xampp I had installed? I did nothing to the code itself when I plugged it into the new htdocs folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the following items to determine why require_once() is returnning a FATAL error:

1. Verify that the file /opt/lampp/htdocs/lr/core/init.php exists.
2. Verify the owner of the file. The file should be owned by the user that is running PHP.
3. Verify that the user running PHP has read access to the file.

Comment: Thanks. I went and made sure that the user matched me instead of the root user, which it didn't.